# Getting Typescript error from MUI Autocomplete source code

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, mui-autocomplete

Following the source code from MUI docs to build a simple autocomplete component:

```
<Autocomplete
    disablePortal
    id="combo-box-demo"
    options={allGroups}
    sx={{ width: 300 }}
    renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Groups" />}
  />
```

This is giving a type error on the Textfield component (coming from `params`), which bubbles down to:

```
Type '"small" | undefined' is not assignable to type 'OverridableStringUnion<"small" | "medium", TextFieldPropsSizeOverrides>'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'OverridableStringUnion<"small" | "medium", TextFieldPropsSizeOverrides>'.ts(2375)
```

So the source code types are just broken?

Is there a workaround or alternative component I can pass to `renderInput`?

Comment: hm, maybe try to restart TS server in your IDE. Look nothing wrong w their type. I also use that in my project but still fine, what is your MUI version?

Comment: Restarted the TS server, killed + reopened the VSCode window, no change... Still seeing the same error. Tried with version 5.14.11 and 5.14.14